# What is the goal of the java.nio.file.CopyOption interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns, nio

I'm confused about the design of JDK7 nio package (which I use often). Take for example `Files.copy`, which takes instances of `CopyOption`'s which is an empty interface, e.g. implemented by `StandardCopyOption`:

```
public enum StandardCopyOption implements CopyOption {
    REPLACE_EXISTING
    COPY_ATTRIBUTES,
    ATOMIC_MOVE;
}

public interface CopyOption {
}
```

What is the idea behind such a design? I mean, even though the `CopyOption` interfaces is passed to `Files.copy`, `Files.copy` has still a compile-time dependency on `StandardCopyOption` (see source-code of `Files.copy`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice there are two different enums that implement `CopyOption`: `StandardCopyOption` and `LinkOption`.  Since the semantics of the two overlap (`LinkOption` applies to links, but *also* during copy operations), having a superinterface allows the API for `copy()` to be cleaner since it takes a varargs list of `CopyOption`, which can contain instances of either enum.